# How to set Biderect permission edit in roles salesforce

Tags: permissions, owd

i wanted to give access edit (Lower and upper) if they are in same hierarchy.
Example:

- SMG SDH

  - SMG SPV

    - SMG ADM
- JKT SDH

  - JKT SPV

    - JKT ADM

i want Jkt spv can edit both of jkt sdh and adm, but cannot edit SMG SPV, SMG sdh, adm.
i tried to give owd permission = read/write, profile permission modify all
but jkt can edit smg. is there something that i can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict access to edit records, you'll need to start with a Read-Only or Private Org Wide Default. You can then provide access to the records owned by users in specific roles using an Owner-Based Sharing Rule. If you use the 'Roles and Internal Subordinates' option and choose the top level role of the branch in the hierarchy (e.g. JKT SDH) when selecting who the records are owned by and who they should be shared with, you'll be able to use a single Sharing Rule for each of the branches of your hierarchy.

This help article covers how to create the sharing rules: [Create Owner-Based Sharing Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_rules_owner.htm&type=5)